# simple Image class not working, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, image-resizing

can someone see what i am not doing right that no image is getting uploaded?

i am trying to resize image with simpleImage class

here is my code

```
if($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
            {
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                $cname = str_replace(' ', '-', $candidate_name);
                $file_name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/", "", $cname);
                $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/images/".$image_name);
                $image = new SimpleImage();             
                $image->load($fileUpload);
                $image->resize(150,180);
                $resize_rename = $fileUpload.$file_name;
                $image->save($resize_rename);                                   
                unlink($fileUpload); //delete the original file             
                    $img = ''.$resize_rename.'';
                }else{
                    $img = '';
                }
```

images are not getting uploaded to the uploads/images/ either instead a file without extension is getting uploaded into the root directory.

Comment: What's the form that's posting to the PHP file? Please create a self-contained example that can show the problem. Does `var_dump($_FILES)` give you any useful information? It'll tell you exactly what the content of `$_FILES` is, so you know if it's an issue with the code or what's being submitted (if the expected values inside `$_FILES` aren't there).

Comment: i saw a file got uploaded to root folder without any extension

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` returns a Boolean so `$fileUpload` is not the path to the image

Comment: @RamRaider please help out with the right way to do it. will appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to test this might have errors but you should, I think, use the path for the file that has been moved as input to the `SimpleImage` class ( but have never looked at that class )

```
$img=false;

if( isset( $candidate_name ) && !empty( $_FILES['file'] ) ){
    $obj=(object)$_FILES['file'];
    $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
    $name=$obj->name;

    $cname = str_replace( ' ', '-', $candidate_name );
    $fname = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/', '', $cname );

    $target = __DIR__ . '/uploads/images/' . $name;
    $status = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $target );

    if( $status ){

        $newname = __DIR__. '/uploads/images/' . $fname;

        $image = new SimpleImage();
        $image->load( $target );
        $image->resize( 150, 180 );
        $image->save( $newname );

        @unlink( $target );
        $img=$newname;
    }
}
```